# Aggregate count of documents with field value that's bigger than threshold

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data in a ES cluster that looks like this:

```
{myField: 123.5, @timestamp: 2021-03-02T11:00:00.000Z}
{myField: 23.5, @timestamp: 2021-03-02T11:01:00.000Z}
{myField: 2023.0, @timestamp: 2021-03-02T11:02:00.000Z}
{myField: 456.7, @timestamp: 2021-03-02T11:02:00.000Z}
{myField: 504.1, @timestamp: 2021-03-02T11:03:00.000Z}
{myField: 321.0, @timestamp: 2021-03-02T11:04:00.000Z}
{myField: 789.0, @timestamp: 2021-03-02T11:05:00.000Z}
...
```

And I'd like to get the count of how many documents have the `myField` value above a certain threshold, say `100`.

Is there a way to have Elasticsearch aggregate this for multiple fields (say `myField2`, `myField3`, etc) in one go?

The only way I can think of doing this is to use the query DSL for every field:

```
POST my-index/_search?size=0&_source=false

{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "hostname.keyword": {
                        "query": "my-host"
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2021-03-02T11:00:00.000Z",
                            "lte": "2021-03-09T11:00:00.000Z",
                            "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "myField": {
                            "gte": 100
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I'd like to avoid this as I have more than 50 fields for which I need to aggregate this and I want to avoid making multiple requests.

Comment: using the query block to filter the data you want to aggregate is exactly the way to go (I'd move also your must condition into the filter block, though).. I'm not sure I understood your problem with this approach

Comment: @Roland do you have an actual aggregation query? What you've shared concerns only the hits but I'm seeing `size=0` which indicates there will be *some* aggregation query.

Comment: @glenacota ok. I thought ES provides some way to aggregate similar to their value count. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll updated the question with some data.

Comment: @JoeSorocin I just want to count how many documents have the field value above a certain threshold. I don't want to actually aggregate anything else.

Comment: Hmm, it turns out that you can have a filter agg https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html.